# using DJ Native Swing API Browser...how to display a specific location in web page & how to turn off the Browser's scroll bar?

Tags: java, api, browser, scrollbar

ok that's my problem :
i made a `JPanel` to open web pages but it seams
that it's not working like i want so im looking for a way to make the 
DJ NATIVE SWING-SWT API `JWebBrowser` open a specific location on web site only
and i turn off the scroll bars vertical or horziontal...
so is it possible to do this?
need your help, please answer.
P.S :
i tried these methods to turn off scrolling:

```
JwebBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
JwebBrowser.setButtonBarVisible(false);
JwebBrowser.setLocationBarVisible(false);
```

but i think they have nothing to do with scrolling....

Comment: Stop re-posting the same question if you don't get replies to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bars are part of the native component. In fact, if you have frame sets or text components, there can be lots of scroll bars in the same page.

One way of hiding scroll bars is I think to inject Javascript once the target page is loaded that would do this task.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what Christopher was getting at. This is similar to the code I used to make sure the rendered native component was at its maximum size.  The +20 I found was enough of a fudge to overcome any inconsistencies.

```
    String js_getHeight = 
    "var D = document;"+
    "return Math.max("+
    "    Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),"+
    "    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),"+
    "    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)"+
    ");";
String js_getWidth = 
    "var D = document;"+
    "return Math.max("+
    "    Math.max(D.body.scrollWidth, D.documentElement.scrollWidth),"+
    "    Math.max(D.body.offsetWidth, D.documentElement.offsetWidth),"+
    "    Math.max(D.body.clientWidth, D.documentElement.clientWidth)"+
    ");";
webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserAdapter(){
      @Override public void loadingProgressChanged(WebBrowserEvent e) {
             if(e.getWebBrowser().getLoadingProgress()==100){
                      NativeComponent nComp = webBrowser.getNativeComponent();
                      double width = Double.parseDouble(webBrowser.executeJavascriptWithResult(js_getWidth).toString())+20;
                      double height = Double.parseDouble(webBrowser.executeJavascriptWithResult(js_getHeight).toString())+20;
                      nComp.setSize(new Dimension((int)width, (int)height));
             }
      }
});
```